# Templatized Observor Pattern

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Implementing a observor pattern. I wish every observor to store a pointer to what subject it is registered to. Therefore every observor has a pointer Subject* and a setSubject(Subject*) func.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

template <class T>
class Subject;

template <class T>
class Observor
{
  public :
  virtual void update(const T& t) = 0;
  virtual ~Observor(){}

  void setSubject(Subject<T>* subjectPtr)
  {
    _subject = subjectPtr;
  }

   private:
   Subject<T>* _subject;
};

template<class T>
class Subject
{
  public :
  virtual void registerObservor(std::shared_ptr< Observor<T> > obv) = 0;
  virtual ~Subject(){}
};

template<class T>
class WeatherStation : public Subject<T>
{
  public :
  void registerObservor(std::shared_ptr< Observor<T> > obv)
  {
    obv->setSubject(this);
    _observors.insert(obv);
  }

  private :
  std::set< std::shared_ptr< Observor<T> > > _observors;
};

class StatisticsDisplay : public Observor<int>
{
  public :
  void update(int data){ std::cout<<"Statistics Display"; }
};
```

The main below compiles without an issue.

```
int main()
{
  WeatherStation<int> wStation;
}
```

However, when the main is changed to

```
int main()
{
  WeatherStation<int> wStation;
  auto sDisplay = std::make_shared<StatisticsDisplay>();
}
```

The code fails to compile now. It tells me the error is in alloc_traits.h: line 254. Since alloc_traits.h is a standard library, the error is definitely in my code. I'm however at loss to what is going wrong.

Comment: even though the error is in `alloc_traits.h`, it would still be helpful if you post the exact error message.

Comment: You should probably wind up from the other side, making `Subject` a shared instance among the observers, and not vice versa. That design approach looks pretty silly (besides the compiler errors).

Comment: Again: mixing templates and virtual functions is no good (however there use cases: boost:::any)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
void update(const int& data){ std::cout<<"Statistics Display"; }
```

instead of

```
void update(int data){ std::cout<<"Statistics Display"; }
```

in `StatisticsDisplay`. Otherwise, `StatisticsDisplay` remains a pure virtual class.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile using [`clang`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e70c3f4a7359ac92) you get descriptive warnings and error messages:

```
main.cpp:49:8: warning: 'StatisticsDisplay::update' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]

  void update(int data) { std::cout<<"Statistics Display"; }

       ^

main.cpp:12:16: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'Observor<int>::update' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter ('const int &' vs 'int')

  virtual void update(const T& t) = 0;
...

main.cpp:12:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'update' in 'StatisticsDisplay'

  virtual void update(const T& t) = 0;

               ^
```

In order to compile your code, you need to change `StatisticsDisplay::update` to match the signature of the virtual function:

```
class StatisticsDisplay : public Observor<int>
{
  public :
  void update(const int& data){ std::cout<<"Statistics Display"; }
};
```

Comment: Dosent really address the issue. It still gives the same compile error.

Comment: @PranavKapoor what? it compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e6887ee489e320b

Comment: its not compiling on code blocks 13.12. I believe they use gcc